# Storing mathematical operators in variable?

Tags: javascript

The issue is simple, but I didn't found what I wanted yet. Basic example:

```js
const firstNumber = 5;
const secondNumber = 3;

let operator = "-";

const string = `${firstNumber} ${operator} ${secondNumber}`;

const unfortunatelyNaN = Number(string);

console.log(string, unfortunatelyNaN)
```

The above is just my way of thinking, but anything which makes me able to dynamically change the operator is fine. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the actual problem here, since this seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What i get is you need to perform arithmetic operation on  two numbers Just use eval(string); instead of Number(string);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change from `Number` to `eval` method

```js
const firstNumber = 5;
const secondNumber = 3;

let operator = "-";

const string = `${firstNumber} ${operator} ${secondNumber}`;

const unfortunatelyNaN = eval(string);

console.log(string, unfortunatelyNaN)
```